# Retrieving data is slow when using PHP with Xcode

Tags: php, xcode

I am building an app that connected to MySql using PHP on my website, the code is working but sometimes it takes long time to fill the TableView in my app. Also sometimes the screen is jamming for a while. I do not know what is happening, I am new with Xcode. Here is my Xcode code:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {



// check connection    
if (![self connected])
{

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"This app needs internet connection" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];

} else

{

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
jasonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];




    listArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (int i = 0; i < jasonArray.count; i++) {

        NSString *cQasidaName = [[jasonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"qasidaName"];
        NSString *cQasidaShaerName = [[jasonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"qasidaShaerName"];
        NSString *cQasidaBody = [[jasonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"qasidaBody"];
        NSString *cQasidaDate = [[jasonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"myDate"];
        NSString *cQasidaTime = [[jasonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"myTime"];
        NSString *cQasidaRate = [[jasonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"myRate"];
        NSString *cQasidaId = [[jasonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"qasidaId"];
        NSString *cQasidaUserName = [[jasonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"userName"];
        NSString *cTheUserId = [[jasonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"theUserId"];
        NSString *cTheUserNameArabic = [[jasonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"userNameArabic"];

            [listArray addObject:[[ListOfObjects alloc] initWithQasidaName: (NSString *) cQasidaName andQasidaShaerName: (NSString *) cQasidaShaerName andQasidaBody: (NSString *) cQasidaBody andQasidaDate: (NSString *) cQasidaDate andQasidaTime: (NSString *) cQasidaTime andQasidaRate: (NSString *)cQasidaRate andQasidaId:cQasidaId andQasidaUserName:cQasidaUserName andTheUserId:cTheUserId andTheUserNameArabic:cTheUserNameArabic]];
        }

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }



    NSLog(@"Total user are: %lu",(unsigned long)listArray.count);


    NSString *strFromInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)listArray.count];
    UITabBarItem *tbi = (UITabBarItem*)[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:0];

    [tbi setBadgeValue:strFromInt];

}
```

And here is my PHP file:

```
<?php

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxx","xxx");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}



  $sql = "SELECT * FROM theQasida ORDER BY qasidaId DESC";
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8mb4');
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
    // to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

// Close connections
mysqli_close($result);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Can any one help in solving this issue? Or direct me to improve the above code.

Thanks

Comment: From dataWithContentsOfURL's documentation:

Do not use this synchronous method to request network-based URLs. For network-based URLs, this method can block the current thread for tens of seconds on a slow network, resulting in a poor user experience, and in iOS, may cause your app to be terminated.

Instead, for non-file URLs, consider using the dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler: method of the NSSession class. See URL Loading System Programming Guide for details.

Comment: Thanks, is there any example you can assist me with at to be a start point?

Comment: There's some sample code at the bottom of this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html